# What's the advantage of using jQuery UI instead of Twitter Bootstrap V2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been using jQuery Ui for a while. It does a good job but then there's some delay after page load and until the jQuery has finished changing the DOM. One thing that concerns me is the time it has taken for the UI components to come out. For example I think they've been developing the menu for a couple of years and it seems like it won't be in production for perhaps one more year.

I just recently started to look at Twitter Bootstrap. It's using Less and has new concepts including a grid and some typo style things and more. It's not quite got the look of jQuery UI, it has no datepicker ( I don't need one anyway ).

My code could easily be changed from jQuery UI to Twitter.

Can someone tell me of any reason why I should not change to the Twitter Bootstrap. I think I'll go ahead and do it but I wonder if there's something that I really need with jQuery UI that I can't get with Twitter Bootstrap.

Comment: Are you sure the performance problems you are seeing are jQuery UI's fault? The [demos](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/) are working nicely for me, and I've never experienced any notable problems using it

Comment: Here's a project that will help you to jumpstart your integration of bootstrap and JQuery UI if you want to try using both of them: http://addyosmani.github.com/jquery-ui-bootstrap/

Answer (score 3):

While there is some overlapping functionality, Bootstrap and jqueryUI are not competing packages. JQuery UI brings interactions (like draggable or resizable), certain widgets, and some effects that Bootstrap doesn't have.

If you only use jquery UI to create widgets like buttons or tabs, you might be able to just switch to bootstrap2 cold turkey. However, there's no reason you wouldn't be able to bootstrap your site and pick the jquery UI features you want piecemeal to import into your project.

Answer (score 1):

You can use both of them , i dont see why you could not use both together. if you think jQuery ui takes too much time to load you should build your own version with only the components you really use , and not just load all the core + css + images + themes ...